# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin code added but nothing is happening

Tags: server, apache2, amazon-ec2, aws, .htaccess

I am trying to solve the below option on my website

```
Strict-Transport-Security
Content-Security-Policy 
X-Frame-Options 
X-Content-Type-Options 
Referrer-Policy 
Permissions-Policy
```

I found the below code on Google and added the same in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
       Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</Directory>
```

After adding the above code I am getting below error

```
sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have scanned my website in this URL: https://securityheaders.com/, and it shows an F result. here is the result link

I have to solve those issues, so I researched Google and found the header code to add to the Apache config file. so I have added the same code and got an error...

Comment: Why are you playing with CORS? You have serious configuration problems to solve long before you can implement CORS. The first thing I would do is enable the firewall and prevent all public access to that server or turn if off and start over. If you have not been hacked already, you are a prime target. Warning: your screenshot shows your public IP address.

Comment: @JohnHanley, removed ip address, Thank you

Comment: You edited the post. That does not remove the IP address from Stack Overflow. Almost everyone can see post edits.